# Legal text on Ask Ubuntu Chat needs to be updated

Tags: bug, legal, askubuntu

The [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) say,

> When accessing the askubuntu.com, meta.askubuntu.com, or chat.askubuntu.com sites ("AskUbuntu"), Subscriber will also abide by the Ubuntu Code of Conduct, which can be found at http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct, and is hereby incorporated by reference, but solely with regard to AskUbuntu. Subscribers with moderator privileges on AskUbuntu agree to abide by the Ubuntu Leadership Code of Conduct, which can be found at http://www.ubuntu.com/community/leadership-conduct, and is hereby incorporated by reference, but solely with regard to moderators on AskUbuntu.

However, `chat.askubuntu.com` does not actually exist. AU chat has been integrated into the general SE chat. That text should be updated.

(Actually, I'd like to see the whole "chat room" stuff changed, so that we had `chat.english.stackexchange.com` and, of course `chat.askubuntu.com`. It would be a lot easier to understand.)

Comment: chat.askubuntu.com doesn't exist...are you *sure*? :)

Comment: @NickCraver. It exists as a redirect only.

Comment: I'm aware of that, so does http://askdifferent.com and several other sites, being a redirect is by no means "not existing".

Comment: It does not exist in the sense that it does not contain any content, so special regulations for such non-existent content are problematic. You can't really apply rules for "the place redirected to from `chat.askubuntu.com`, can you?

Comment: It redirects, so it has content.  Furthermore it's not equivalent to visiting `chat.stackexchange.com` directly, it's a special view based either on the redirect or the site you came from.  This view is scoped to the site `askubuntu.com` and *is* directly relevant...I don't see the what the issue is here.